# Finance Lib with portfolio optimization method in python

Tags: python, finance

I'm looking for a finance library in python which offers a method similar to the MATLAB's [portalloc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/finance/portalloc.html) . It is used to optimize a portfolio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know linear algebra, there is a simple function for solving the optimization problem which any library should support.  Unfortunately, it's been so long since I researched it I can't tell you the formula nor a library that supports it, but a little research should reveal it.  The main point is that any linear algebra library should do.

Update:

Here's a quote from a post I found.

> Some research says that "mean variance portfolio optimization" can
>   give good results. I discussed this in a message
>
> To implement this approach, a needed input is the covariance matrix of
>   returns, which requires historical stock prices, which one can obtain
>   using "Python quote grabber" http://www.openvest.org/Databases/ovpyq .
>
> For expected returns -- hmmm. One of the papers I cited found that
>   assuming equal expected returns of all stocks can give reasonable
>   results.
>
> Then one needs a "quadratic programming" solver, which appears to be
>   handled by the CVXOPT Python package.
>
> If someone implements the approach in Python, I'd be happy to hear
>   about it.
>
> There is a "backtest" package in R (open source stats package callable
>   from Python) http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backtest/index.html
>   "for exploring portfolio-based hypotheses about financial instruments
>   (stocks, bonds, swaps, options, et cetera)."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this [library](http://www.downv.com/Mac/download-Python-statlib-10009752.htm) (statlib) or this [one](http://www.downv.com/Mac/download-Mystic-10004716.htm) (Mystic) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to define your objective function. You can use [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/optimize.html) to solve almost any portfolio optimization problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python implementations of some typical portfolio optimizations can be found at https://github.com/czielinski/portfolioopt. The corresponding quadratic programs are being solved using the `CVXOPT` library. *(Disclaimer: this is my own GitHub repository.)*

Answer (score 0):

I am new but I believe gradient descent is what you are looking for. Michael Chu, who is author of optopsy 2.0 python library   (https://github.com/michaelchu/optopsy), has great insights into implementation. Works great with v3.7.

Comment: The method involves lagrange multipliers for portfolio optimization but it escapes me the name of it.