# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'colmap' in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am a python beginner and I try to use the following code from this source: [Portfolio rebalancing with bandwidth method in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745160/portfolio-rebalancing-with-bandwidth-method-in-python)

The code works well so far.

The problem is that if I want to call the function not as usual like `rebalance(df, tol)`, but from a certain location in the dataframe on, like: `rebalance(df[500:], tol)`, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'colmap'`. So my question is: how do I have to adjust the code in order to make this possible?

Here is the code:

---

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as PID

def setup_df():
    df1 = PID.get_data_yahoo("IBM", 
                             start=DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1), 
                             end=DT.datetime.today())
    df1.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'ibm'}, inplace=True)

    df2 = PID.get_data_yahoo("F", 
                             start=DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1), 
                             end=DT.datetime.today())
    df2.rename(columns={'Adj Close': 'ford'}, inplace=True)

    df = df1.join(df2.ford, how='inner')
    df = df[['ibm', 'ford']]
    df['sh ibm'] = 0
    df['sh ford'] = 0
    df['ibm value'] = 0
    df['ford value'] = 0
    df['ratio'] = 0
    # This is useful in conjunction with iloc for referencing column names by
    # index number
    df.colmap = dict([(col, i) for i,col in enumerate(df.columns)])
    return df

def invest(df, i, amount):
    """
    Invest amount dollars evenly between ibm and ford
    starting at ordinal index i.
    This modifies df.
    """
    c = df.colmap
    halfvalue = amount/2
    df.iloc[i:, c['sh ibm']] = halfvalue / df.iloc[i, c['ibm']]
    df.iloc[i:, c['sh ford']] = halfvalue / df.iloc[i, c['ford']]

    df.iloc[i:, c['ibm value']] = (
        df.iloc[i:, c['ibm']] * df.iloc[i:, c['sh ibm']])
    df.iloc[i:, c['ford value']] = (
        df.iloc[i:, c['ford']] * df.iloc[i:, c['sh ford']])
    df.iloc[i:, c['ratio']] = (
        df.iloc[i:, c['ibm value']] / df.iloc[i:, c['ford value']])

def rebalance(df, tol):
    """
    Rebalance df whenever the ratio falls outside the tolerance range.
    This modifies df.
    """
    i = 0
    amount = 100
    c = df.colmap
    while True:
        invest(df, i, amount)
        mask = (df['ratio'] >= 1+tol) | (df['ratio'] <= 1-tol)
        # ignore prior locations where the ratio falls outside tol range
        mask[:i] = False
        try:
            # Move i one index past the first index where mask is True
            # Note that this means the ratio at i will remain outside tol range
            i = np.where(mask)[0][0] + 1
        except IndexError:
            break
        amount = (df.iloc[i, c['ibm value']] + df.iloc[i, c['ford value']])
    return df

df = setup_df()
tol = 0.05 #setting the bandwidth tolerance
rebalance(df, tol)

df['portfolio value'] = df['ibm value'] + df['ford value']
df["ibm_weight"] = df['ibm value']/df['portfolio value']
df["ford_weight"] = df['ford value']/df['portfolio value']

print df['ibm_weight'].min()
print df['ibm_weight'].max()
print df['ford_weight'].min()
print df['ford_weight'].max()

# This shows the rows which trigger rebalancing
mask = (df['ratio'] >= 1+tol) | (df['ratio'] <= 1-tol)
print(df.loc[mask])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you encountered is due to a poor design decision on my part.
`colmap` is an attribute defined on `df` in `setup_df`:

```
df.colmap = dict([(col, i) for i,col in enumerate(df.columns)])
```

It is not a standard attribute of a DataFrame.

`df[500:]` returns a new DataFrame which is generated by copying data from `df` into the new DataFrame. Since `colmap` is not a standard attribute, it is not copied into the new DataFrame.

To call `rebalance` on a DataFrame other than the one returned by `setup_df`,  replace `c = df.colmap` with

```
c = dict([(col, j) for j,col in enumerate(df.columns)])
```

I've made this change in [the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30804273/190597) as well.

PS. In the other question, I had chosen to define `colmap` on `df` itself so
that this dict would not have to be recomputed with every call to `rebalance`
and `invest`.

Your question shows me that this minor optimization is not worth making these
functions so dependent on the specialness of the DataFrame returned by
`setup_df`.

---

There is a second problem you will encounter using `rebalance(df[500:], tol)`:

Since `df[500:]` returns a *copy* of a portion of `df`, `rebalance(df[500:], tol)` will modify 
this copy and not the original `df`. If the object, `df[500:]`,
has no reference outside of `rebalance(df[500:], tol)`, it will be garbage
collected after the call to `rebalance` is completed. So the entire computation
would be lost.  Therefore `rebalance(df[500:], tol)` is not useful.

Instead, you could modify `rebalance` to accept `i` as a parameter:

```
def rebalance(df, tol, i=0):
    """
    Rebalance df whenever the ratio falls outside the tolerance range.
    This modifies df.
    """
    c = dict([(col, j) for j, col in enumerate(df.columns)])
    while True:
        mask = (df['ratio'] >= 1+tol) | (df['ratio'] <= 1-tol)
        # ignore prior locations where the ratio falls outside tol range
        mask[:i] = False
        try:
            # Move i one index past the first index where mask is True
            # Note that this means the ratio at i will remain outside tol range
            i = np.where(mask)[0][0] + 1
        except IndexError:
            break
        amount = (df.iloc[i, c['ibm value']] + df.iloc[i, c['ford value']])
        invest(df, i, amount)
    return df
```

Then you can rebalance `df` starting at the 500th row using

```
rebalance(df, tol, i=500)
```

Note that this finds the first row *on or after* i=500 that needs
rebalancing. It does not necessarily rebalance at i=500 itself. This allows you to call `rebalance(df, tol, i)` for arbitrary `i` without having to determine in advance if rebalancing is required on row `i`.